# JQuery image gallery on JSP

Tags: jquery, jsp, image-gallery

Right now I have a small media portal project (Servlet API/JSP) on which you can upload and view images. Now I want to add some kind of JQuery image gallery plugin into my project for viewing images. I have basic knowledge of Jquery. 
How can I achieve this? With which plugin? From what should I start?

Thanks in advice. 
Nazar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to have a look at the following: http://blueimp.github.io/Bootstrap-Image-Gallery/ Twitter Bootstrap is used for this gallery and Twitter Bootstrap is very easy to use especially given that only a very basic understanding of jQuery is required to get most of the fancy functions working.

Comment: Ok, I think this fits. How can I include this plugin into my code to start using it?

Comment: It is very simple to integrate into a JSP/Servlet web application. All you have to do is follow the instructions here: http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/getting-started.html as this gets you started. Then, you can include the CSS and bootstrap.js into your JSP file. But, the key is to follow the link given in this comment as that really gets you going.

Comment: What about my current project's style? Will it be overriden by bootstrap css?

Comment: However, to add the image gallery along with Twitter Bootstrap, you may have to download the following from GitHub: https://github.com/blueimp/Bootstrap-Image-Gallery With your current project's style, it may be overridden by Twitter Bootstrap. Therefore, I recommend you download and include only the minimum files (CSS/JS) and then delete the CSS classes you don't need/want.

Comment: Thank you :)
You are a great help